# message broker with different message types by string

Tags: design-patterns, cross-platform, msmq

I am looking for a nice way to handle diffrent types of messages of type string (cross platform).

Imagine the next scenario:

we have a method: `onMessageReceive(String message)`
value of the parameter: 'order.new:1' or 'orderstatus.update:12' etc

now we can split the message in 'action' and 'parameter' by seperator ':'

```
String action = 'order.new'
String parameter = '1'
```

We can put this in a `if-else` statement

```
if (message.equels("order.new") {
    // get the order

} else if (message.equels("orderstatus.update") {
    // get the new order status<br/>
}
```

But i dont like it this way. It is "ok" if there are only 2 actions but what if there are 50 actions.

What are the other solutions (cross platform)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a generic message handler interface with a single method

```
  interface MessageHandler {
     void handleMessage(String parameter);
  }
```

Then, you could have a registry of handlers, one handler for each type of message. The registry could have an interface like this:

```
  class HandlersRegistry {
      public MessageHandler getHandler(String handlerType);
      public void addHandler(String handlerType, MessageHandler handler);
  }
```

Internally, handlers registry can store a map that would map a string (handler type) to an appropriate MessageHandler object. This way you avoid long if-else or switch statements and you can easily extend the code to handle new types of messages.